# Electrical energy and power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Two resistance 2 ohm and 6 ohm are connected in parallel and the combination is then connected to a source of EMF 12V.how much power is consumed in each resistance?

Comment: Nit-picking:  Power can not be "consumed";  it is the rate of consuming energy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the two resistors $R_1$ and $R_2$. Since they are connected in parallel, we have that the voltages over both resistors are the same (12V in this case).

The power generated is defined as:

$P = U * I$

By Ohm's law we have:

$I = \frac{U}{R}$

Plugging this result in the first formula:

$ P = \frac{U^2}{R}$

Using this formula you can calculate the power consumption per resistor.